# Not overflow when two layouts overlap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a responsive medium view where I have implemented swipe functionality. I have two layouts (asideFilters and content-results) that I can toggle to view one or another. When I swipe to asideFilters the content-results layout stays behind asideFilters. This is correct, but it also overflows asideFilters.

If I set the content-results to `display: none` with JavaScript, the asideFilters layout also disappears so I just see the footer. How could I make the div of content-results not overflow when asideFilters is on, without affecting asideFilters?

Here is my code:

```
<div class= "row outer">

  // asideFilters layout, that is positioned to the left off screen 
  <div class= "aside-filters-medium inner">
  </div>
  // content-results layout, that is the view when DOMContentLoad
  <div class= "head-content-results">
  </div>
  <div class="content-results">
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .outer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative; 
   }

  .inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100vw;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5; 
   }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: can you create a fiddle please? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I'm not capable to build a fiddle with this because I don't know how to require external libraries. my web uses like Hammer.js or Foundation. I can set in Frameworks & Extensions JQuery 1.11.0 but when I ty to swipe in the fiddel it does nothing, so it wouldn't be too helpfull